# Integrating WinJS and Angular2

Tags: winjs, angular

I'm trying to wrap a [WinJS rating control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465489.aspx) in an **Angular2** component. When I debug, I can see that **WinJS.UI.processAll();** is being called and executed. But I don't see the rating control.

How can I make it work?

**Dashboard.cshtml**:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
}

<my-app></my-app>

<script src="/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="/config.js"></script>

<script>
    System.import('reflect-metadata')
        .then(function () {
            System.import('angular2')
                .then(function () {
                    System.import("/js/app");
                });
        });
</script>
```

**app.js**:

```
import { Component, View, bootstrap } from 'angular2';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'winjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    template: '<div data-win-control=\'WinJS.UI.Rating\' data-win-options=\'{averageRating: 3.4}\'></div>'
})
class MyAppComponent {
    constructor() {
    }

    onInit() {
        WinJS.UI.processAll();
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

Comment: For what I see in [Adding the Windows Library for JavaScript to your page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465493.aspx) you are missing the stylesheets. Try this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/MBSuu8?p=preview

Comment: I forgot to mention, assuming you are using alpha37, you must implement `OnInit` and import it as well. All that is included in the plnkr.

Comment: Thank you. I added the style sheet (<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.3.0/css/ui-light.min.css" />) to the cshtml file and it worked. If you can add your reply as the answer, I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested by @wonderfulworld

First of all, according to [Adding the Windows Library for JavaScript to your page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465493.aspx#including_winjs) you must add the css file to your html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.3.0/css/ui-light.min.css">
```

Second thing, from alpha37+ you must import and implement the lifecycle hook you're using, `onInit` in this case (see [remove LifecycleEvent](https://github.com/vicb/angular/commit/ecfed76847beb7450b88aa0a7c0f1e7d62a638e4)).

```
import { Component, View, bootstrap, OnInit} from 'angular2/angular2';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'winjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    template: '<div data-win-control=\'WinJS.UI.Rating\' data-win-options=\'{averageRating: 3.4}\'></div>'
})
class MyAppComponent implements OnInit {
    onInit() {
        WinJS.UI.processAll();
    }
}
```

And that would be all. Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MBSuu8?p=preview).

Glad it helped ;)